# Sonar scan - Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly

Tags: java, sonarqube, clone, mutable

When I do a sonar scan I get the vulnerability "Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly". The resolution for this is also provided where it is mentioned that we should clone the mutable object or return unmodifiable list.
However if I clone the object and later on if I want to update the value then how can I access the original object because I have returned the cloned object?
Any thoughts on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

> However if I clone the object and later on if I want to update the value then how can I access the original object because I have returned the cloned object

You don't. At least not from the caller.

I'll go out on a limb here and say we're talking about a list, so:

```
public class MyClass {
  private List<String> strings;

  public List<String> getStrings(){ 
    // returns a copy, so member list is still intact
    return new ArrayList<String>(strings);
  }

  public void addString(String newString) {
    strings.add(newString);
  }

  public void dropString(String oldString) {
    strings.remove(oldString);
  }

  public void replaceString(String oldString, String newString) {
    dropString(oldString);
    addString(newString);
  }
}
```

In other words, you control access to member actions through the owning class. If you truly want a public member that anyone can get and update (not that I recommend that) then drop the getter and make the member `public`.

Comment: There is one more point which I got after a discussion among st developers. If the caller is from our system/application and not from outside then still passing mutable object will be a vulnerability? Because even if the caller changes the mutable object since it is from inside the system this should not affect the system.

Comment: @Swapneel I'm no security expert, but I believe assuming the caller will only and always be "internal" is considered risky. But then security people are paranoid by both nature and nuture.

Comment: Is cloning every Collection object in the application create memory issues. The getter method can be called from multiple places. So the cloning happens multiple times.